# Delete row based on nulls in certain columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to drop a row from a DataFrame containing all nulls OR a single null but can you drop a row based on the nulls for a specified set of columns?

For example, say I am working with data containing geographical info (city, latitude, and longitude) in addition to numerous other fields. I want to keep the rows that at a minimum contain a value for city OR for lat and long but drop rows that have null values for all three.

I am having trouble finding functionality for this in pandas documentation. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: mate, it's in the documentation. Check the help for the [dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) function

Comment: @GeneBurinsky, no, `dropna()` will work incorrectly in this case. Check a row with index `4` in my example. `df.dropna(subset=['city','latitude','longitude'], how='all')` will drop it...

Comment: @MaxU, that is a fair point. However, at least fo your example, this will work `df.dropna(axis=0, subset=[['city', 'longitude', 'latitude']], thresh=2)` but in general, you're right, explicit logical statements for what is desired are superior to the `dropna` solution

Comment: @GeneBurinsky, wow! i've completely missed out this parameter... Could you please write it as an answer?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pd.dropna` but instead of using `how='all'` and `subset=[]`, you can use the `thresh` parameter to require a minimum number of NAs in a row before a row gets dropped. In the city, long/lat example, a `thresh=2` will work because we only drop in case of 3 NAs. Using the great data example set up by MaxU, we would do

```
## get MaxU's example data via copy/paste (ie read_clipboard)
df = pd.read_clipboard()

## remove undesired rows
df.dropna(axis=0, subset=[['city', 'longitude', 'latitude']], thresh=2)
```

This yields:

```
In [5]: df.dropna(axis=0, subset=[['city', 'longitude', 'latitude']], thresh=2)
Out[5]:
  city  latitude  longitude  a  b
0  aaa   11.1111        NaN  1  2
1  bbb       NaN    22.2222  5  6
3  NaN   11.1111    33.3330  1  2
```

Comment: Thanks! Clear and concise solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
  city  latitude  longitude  a  b
0  aaa   11.1111        NaN  1  2
1  bbb       NaN    22.2222  5  6
2  NaN       NaN        NaN  3  4
3  NaN   11.1111    33.3330  1  2
4  NaN       NaN    44.4440  1  1

In [26]: df.query("city == city or (latitude == latitude and longitude == longitude)")
Out[26]:
  city  latitude  longitude  a  b
0  aaa   11.1111        NaN  1  2
1  bbb       NaN    22.2222  5  6
3  NaN   11.1111    33.3330  1  2
```

If i understand OP correctly the row with index `4` must be dropped as not both coordinates are not-null. So `dropna()` won't work "properly" in this case:

```
In [62]: df.dropna(subset=['city','latitude','longitude'], how='all')
Out[62]:
  city  latitude  longitude  a  b
0  aaa   11.1111        NaN  1  2
1  bbb       NaN    22.2222  5  6
3  NaN   11.1111    33.3330  1  2
4  NaN       NaN    44.4440  1  1   # this row should be dropped...
```

Comment: That's correct, index 4 would need to be dropped. This seems to be what I was looking for. I wasn't aware you could use the booleans in this way for query(). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

dropna has a parameter to apply the tests only on a subset of columns:

```
dropna(axis=0, how='all', subset=[your three columns in this list])
```

Comment: Note that, as MaxU mentioned in the comments, this wouldn't quite work on the example test set.

Answer (score 1):

Using a boolean mask and some clever `dot` product (this is for @Boud)

```
subset = ['city', 'latitude', 'longitude']
df[df[subset].notnull().dot([2, 1, 1]).ge(2)]

  city  latitude  longitude  a  b
0  aaa   11.1111        NaN  1  2
1  bbb       NaN    22.2222  5  6
3  NaN   11.1111    33.3330  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform selection by exploiting the bitwise operators.

```
## create example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Gothenburg', None, None], 'Long': [None, 1, 1], 'Lat': [1, None, 1]})

## bitwise/logical operators
~df.City.isnull() | (~df.Lat.isnull() & ~df.Long.isnull())
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

## subset using above statement
df[~df.City.isnull() | (~df.Lat.isnull() & ~df.Long.isnull())]
         City  Lat  Long
0  Gothenburg  1.0   NaN
2        None  1.0   1.0
```